# how would I go about proving that a set of sets is a subset of a power set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

if Z is a set of sets, there exists a set Y where:

Z is a subset of P(Y)

up till now the only idea that I have is that the power set of Y is a set of sets, so it's like B = P(Y) is a set of sets and I want to prove that Z is a subset of B, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Think about it.  Suppose $Z=\{\{1,6,93,129\},\{6,32\},\{7\},\{129,1000\}\}$.  What do you think $Y$ might be?

Comment: @lulu Y would be {1, 6, 93, 129, 32, 7, 1000} right?

Comment: @user771870 remember, sets cannot contain same elements more than once...

Comment: @user771870  Exactly  Can you see how to do it generally?

Comment: @lulu what about $Z = \{\{1,2\},\{\{2,3,4\}\}\}$?

Comment: @gt6989b   $Y=\{1,2\},\{2,3,4\}\}$, same as $Z$.  You are right, of course that it is at least implicitly assumed that the elements of $Z$ live in some universal set.

Comment: @lulu +1, just wanted to clarify that for the OP --  people learning set theory in the beginning often assume they only have to deal with sets of just numbers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

One approach: what happens if you look at the power set of $Z$ itself?

Another: Look at a simple example list $Z = \{\{1,2\},\{2,3,4\}\}$ and a more complex one $Z = \{\{1,2\},\{\{2,3,4\}\}\}$

Comment: will the P(Z) of the first example be { phi, {{1,2}}, {{1,2}, {2,3,4}},  {{2,3,4}}?

Comment: @user771870 yes. Notice how elegantly this deals with multiple sets-of-sets issues in the second approach